# mysql PDO UPDATE WHERE id=?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Can anybody tell me why this is not working

I am trying to create a table with the insert and create a unique id for it, then i wish to update that table on another page, but selecting the table with the unique id.

But for some reason all i get is the 1st insert work, but the update will not.. can anybody help..

Many thanks

CREATE TABLE WITH UNIQUE ID

```
$listID=rand(10,100);

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classifieds2", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this

$query="INSERT INTO `listings` (`username`,`listID`) VALUES (?,?)";

$stat=$db->prepare($query);$stat=$db->prepare($query);

$stat->execute(array("$accountname","$listID"));
```

Then updating that table with the following code, which is not working

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=classifieds2", 'root', ''); // 1. set database with this instead of conect - or change conect to this

$query="UPDATE `listings` SET (`date`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`title`,`info`,`location`,`phone`,`postcode`,`town`,`city`,`image`,`image2`,`image3`,`image4`,`image5`,`price`,`catagory`,`cond`,`delivery`,`username`,`email`,`youtubevideo`,`paypal`,`facebook`,`twitter`,`feedbackscore`) WHERE listID=? VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";


$stat=$db->prepare($query);$stat=$db->prepare($query);


$stat->execute(array("$now","$firstname","$lastname","$sellingtitle","$sellinginfo","$town","$phone1","$postcode","$town","$city","$i0url","$i1url","$i2url","$i3url","$i4url","$price","$catagory","$cond","$delivery","$sellername","$email","$youtubeurl","$paypal","$facebook","$twitter","feedbackscore","$listID"));
```

The `listid`is sent via POST to the receiving page which updates, and the unique ID is inserted into the table from the first query - but the update does not work. Can anyone spot why?

Comment: Whats with all these variables being wrapped in double quotes? Thats needless.

Comment: Set PDO to throw exceptions, and it will tell you what fails.

Comment: Keep in mind, every `?` must have a proper corresponding value in the same location of the array for `execute`. Your `$listID` should be on the front of that array, not the end. Also reduce these to one: `$stat=$db->prepare($query);$stat=$db->prepare($query);`

Comment: Isn't update syntax `update tablename set fieldname=?, field2=? where key=?`

Comment: ok i will try error reports , and the quotes are what i was shown how to do..im a learner you see.

Comment: I am not sure if values can come after where in sql update statement. Anyone?

Comment: $stat=$db->prepare($query);$stat=$db->prepare($query);, oh yes, i didnt see that...thanks

Comment: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(`date`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`title`,`info`,`location`,`phone`,`postcode`,`tow' at line 1 )

Comment: By preference, I would suggest using named parameters in your queries rather than a bunch of question marks. It is more flexible, and also a lot easier to spot errors. Especially when you have a  *lot* of parameters, like you've got here.

Comment: @NigelRen  I am not sure because insert query has two different syntaxes. The `INSERT INTO ..VALUES` and `INSERT INTO... SET(` .Too lazy to check the manual

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Update listings set column1=?, 
column2=? Where column3=?
```